# Does a full-scale Apollo lunar module mock-up exists that allows visitors to explore the inside?

Tags: lunar-module, education, museum-exhibits

The Lunar Module was an utterly amazing spacecraft. It's also one for which getting a feel for the inside is extremely difficult from photos$^*$.

- **Has anyone made a full-scale mock up of the lunar module for the purpose of giving people access to the inside and get a feel of what it was like?**

I could not find any results online and sadly suspect that such an object does not exist. I'd claim it would possibly fill an important need to educate and awe the public. It'd be fantastic to make something like this part of the many Apollo exhibits in museums!

$^*$*Photographic views of the outside from the inside are somewhat disorienting because they are through triangular windows (with a downward orientation), outside photos of course don't give you any idea about the inside, and photos from the inside cannot show much because the space is so small. Having said that, there is an absolutely wonderful 3D/360$^{\circ}$ interactive photo courtesy of the National Air & Space Museum! Short of an actual physical experience this is as good as it gets* https://airandspace.si.edu/multimedia-gallery/lm-interiorjpg

Comment: There exists a LM Simulation Trainer at the "Cradle of Aviation" Museum. The cut open design of the simulator seems to give a good perspective even though it is not accessible.
http://cradleofaviationpr.org/lunar-module-simulator-trainer/

Comment: The audio of the descent of the Eagle that plays continuously makes the display of the training even more of interesting.

Answer (score 6):

The [US Space and Rocket Center](https://www.rocketcenter.com/) (official visitor center of Marshall Space Flight Center) in Huntsville, Alabama has the crew station from one of the Lunar Module Mission Simulators.

You can't get inside, but you can at least look through a full sized door opening.

Picture of the inside

[image]

Front view of the crew station

[image]

Side view of the crew station

[image]

Compare to

[image]

First 3 pictures mine, last picture credit NASA.

This currently unanswered question asks for information about the other simulators: [What is the current location of Link-built Apollo Mission Simulators?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37783/what-is-the-current-location-of-link-built-apollo-mission-simulators)

Comment: Thanks for providing those pictures. They certainly add a perspective. The LM-Simulator in New York cannot be entered (not surprisingly...). But the cut-open design makes for a good perspective! http://cradleofaviationpr.org/lunar-module-simulator-trainer/

Comment: @user2705196 Thanks, that's a much better link than the one I had in my question, I'll replace it.

Comment: I found a 1982 NY Times article about the Cradle of Avaiation museum. In it they quote the curator ' ''This is the only place in the world where you can go into a lunar module,'' Mr. Kaiser said as a visitor took one small step and squeezed through the two-foot opening that serves as an entrance to the lunar module.' This suggests that (surprisingly) the simulator used to be accessible! Unfortunately, the modern exhibit is not for climbing into... And the newspaper article suggests that this was a unique opportunity worldwide.

Comment: @user2705196 wow! Surprising.

Answer (score 2):

Years ago, the National Air and Space Museum had one of the fully-functional LMs on display. You could control the camera inside it and look around. It was the closest I've seen, and I was really upset when a few years later the display was gone.

Also, it was HUGE, at least from my first impression, after having seen it on TV.